# onesignal with react-navigation and redux: i am not able to navigate to screen when notification is opened

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, onesignal

**The problem:**
I need to navigate to a screen when the onesignal notification is opened.

**The situation:**
I can not navigate from my App component cause the navigator is not yet defined.
I can not navigate from my RootContainer component cause the navigator is not yet defined.

I thought about dispatch action instead of navigate, but the same:
I can not dispatch action from my App component cause the store is not yet defined.
I can not dispatch action from my RootContainer component cause the navigation is not yet defined.

This is the App.js:

```
... import

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    version: 1,
    storage,
    blacklist: ['navigation']
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer, {
    is_logged_in: false,
    login_type: null,
    access_token: null
},
    applyMiddleware(logger));

const persistor = persistStore(store);
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        OneSignal.init("...");

        this.onOpened = this.onOpened.bind(this);

        OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
        OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
        OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);

        this.state = {
            notification_offer_clicked: null
        };
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        OneSignal.removeEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
        OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
        OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
    }

    onOpened(openResult) {
        this.setState({
            notification_offer_clicked: openResult.notification.payload.additionalData.offer
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                    <RootContainer notification_offer_clicked={this.state.notification_offer_clicked} />
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default DebugConfig.useReactotron
  ? console.tron.overlay(App)
  : App
```

As you can see I try to pass `notification_offer_clicked` prop to RootContainer to propagate the event.
The prop is correctly passed, but I do not know howto go on from there.

This is Container.js:

```
... import

class RootContainer extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        //if (nextProps.notification_offer_clicked) {
        //    this.props.navigation.navigate('Offer', { 'offer' : nextProps.notification_offer_clicked });
        //}
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AppNavigator />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        is_logged_in: state.is_logged_in,
    };
};

// wraps dispatch to create nicer functions to call within our component
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    startup: () => dispatch(StartupActions.startup())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RootContainer)
```

`AppNavigator` is a `StackNavigator` variable, so I do not know howto (and if its possible) pass props to it.

The problem is if I try to decomment

> this.props.navigation.navigate...

line I get the error cause `navigation` is not yet defined in the RootContainer.

My question is: how can I navigate to a screen (or simply dispatch a redux action) when I open a onesignal notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you initialise the event listeners in your home screen? 
Lets say you have this navigation architecture,

```
SCREEN1: 
- SUBSCREEN1,
- SUBSCREEN2,
```

Now, You can add your event listeners to your Screen1 component.
And to make a dynamic approach, from one signal you can send the route name,
for example. one signal data packet is..

```
    notifications: {
      payload: {
        additionalData: {
        routeName: 'SUBSCREEN1',
        params: {
          id: 12
        }
       }
     }
   }
```

Then you can efficiently navigate from the parent to a nested screen, as you got the routeName and props too... 
Then you can define a simple function, lets say `onOpened`, on your onOpened listener...

```
onOpened = (data) => {
// some validation if there is a data or not,,, if there is
this.props.navigation.navigate(data.notification.payload.additionalData.routeName,data.notification.payload.addtionalData.params);
}
```

Here you passed a routeName and props in a way that it can navigate to any screen with required props,

NOTE: You always need to validate the data before navigating to decrease the number of bugs and crashes. And you don't need event listeners on your root component.

You don't need that because when you click on notification, It waits till it receives an event listener, and as soon as it receives the event listener, it executes the last notificaiton I know its a weird behaviour from `onesignal`.

Comment: I used the code code written in the onesignal documentation. Thats why I put it in the App file.

Comment: you dont need that...I will update my answer with the reason

Comment: I use this method in a production app, and it works flawlessly

Comment: I did not understand the the thing about listener

Comment: Ok...So basically if you have two screens, screen 1, screen 2, currently you are on screen 1, but the screen2 is where the event listeners initialise, when you receive the notification, and lets say you click it, nothing will happen..and when you navigate to screen2 after sometime, Then the onOpened function will fire, so it waits for the event listeners. Thats was the reason, you dont need listeners in root component, Its hard to explain like this. let me know if it helped.